# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents'

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I'm trying to generate an APK for publication in Google store, but I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task
':app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents'. java.io.IOException: The output jar
[/home/nome/Projects/app-android/app/_app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/release/componentClasses.jar]
must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check if this works [Multidex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537333/android-multidex-not-supporting-with-proguard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Progaurd.

Based on these links below it looks like certain Progaurd configurations along with multidex enabled can return this error. Can you try to disable Progaurd?

[Android Build with Gradle and ProGuard : "The output jar must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631149/android-build-with-gradle-and-proguard-the-output-jar-must-be-specified-after)

[Android multidex not supporting with proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537333/android-multidex-not-supporting-with-proguard)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/qU0Me1_2HF8